# How do i get email of the user that is triggering a function in cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am unable to find a way to get email from the user that is triggering a cloud function.

```
    exports.calculateCartTotal = 
functions.firestore.document('users/{userEmail}/userCart/{item}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
    //I want to access the email of the user that has triggered the function here
     });
```

Comment: Does the user email is the value of `userEmail` in `users/{userEmail}/userCart/{item}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#event_parameter_split_into_data_and_context) in the doc:

> The `context` parameter provides information about the function's
>   execution. Identical across asynchronous functions types, `context`
>   contains the fields `eventId`, `timestamp`, `eventType`, `resource`,
>   and `params`.

Making the assumption that the user email you are looking for is the value of `userEmail` in the `users/{userEmail}/userCart/{item}` path, you will get it through the `params` field, as follows:

```
const userEmail = context.params.userEmail;
```

Comment: Sweet. Thanks a lot!